# imshow and pcolormesh show two different outputs with the same input

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

When I am trying to understand the difference between `imshow` and `pcolormesh`, I encounter this problem that I cannot figure out why.

For example, I have a sine wave with frequency 10kHz

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy import fft

f = 10000  # Frequency, in cycles per second, or Hertz
fs = 44100  # Sampling rate, or number of measurements per second

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 5 * fs, endpoint=False)
X = np.sin(f * 2 * np.pi * t)
```

Applying `fft` on this signal gives the spectrogram `Xs`

```
window_size = 2048  # 2048-sample fourier windows
stride = 512        # 512 samples between windows
wps = fs/float(512) # ~86 windows/second
Xs = np.empty([int(2*wps),2048])

for i in range(Xs.shape[0]):
    Xs[i] = np.abs(fft(X[i*stride:i*stride+window_size]))
```

Now I would like to plot the spectrogram `Xs` with both `imshow` and `pcolormesh`.

### Imshow

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.imshow(Xs.T,aspect='auto',cmap='seismic')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

### pcolormesh

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.pcolormesh(Xs.T,cmap='seismic')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

**Why are they different?**

Comment: If you zoom very close on your lines, they are indeed represented in the same way. I am however confused why this does not translate to the large scale visualization.

Comment: You have more image pixels as physical pixels in the graphics. Hence the image needs to be resampled. The result of resampling is different because `imshow` produces an `AxesImage` and `pcolormesh` produces a `QuadMesh`, which is a collection of patches.

Comment: I don't understand the image pixels and physical pixels part, can you elaborate more? My `Xs` has the dimension `(1000,1024)`, is it image pixels or physical pixels?

Comment: Try saving at 300 dpi and you will see a difference

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, adding the argument `dpi` solves the problems. Even setting `dpi=100`, which is the default value if the `dpi` argument is not given, the problem will still be solved.

### Imshow

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7), dpi=100)
plt.imshow(Xs.T,aspect='auto',cmap='seismic')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Although the `dpi` argument solves the problem, I am still not clear about the reasoning behind it. Any extra suggestions are welcomed.